# azure bot can't send messages after some days

Tags: azure, chatbot, azure-bot-service

I have two bots, and they post messages to users with 2-3 days interval.
First of them use proactive messages and works fine.
Second bot use simple messages and can't send messages to user after some days interval. It starts sending new messages only if user write some message to bot, but after 1-2 days it stops again.

I can't find any information about conversation timeout and I don't understand why it happens.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it's possibly a [TrustServiceUrl Issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#avoiding-401-unauthorized-errors) (despite the 500 vs 401 error message).

You can fix it by adding your channel's ServiceUrls to the list of trusted URLs:

```
var serviceUrl = <GetThisFrom Activity.ServiceUrl>;

MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(serviceUrl);
```

[Here's a link](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Connector/Authentication/MicrosoftAppCredentials.cs) to the library, if that helps. Otherwise, [browsing these issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues?q=label%3A%22Trust+Service+URL%22+is%3Aclosed) should help.

It's also possible that your bot is sleeping. You may be able to resolve the issue by going to `Azure Portal > Your App Service > Configuration > General Settings > Always On <enable>`

#### Note to others:

This "Trust Service URL Issue" is pretty common. This happens for lots of other URLs when trying to use Proactive messaging. Just replace `serviceUrl` with whatever is appropriate for your use case. And yes, if you're using multiple channels, you can add multiple URLs when using `MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl()` by calling it multiple times.

Here's [the method definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.connector.authentication.microsoftappcredentials.trustserviceurl?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable). Note: you can add expiration for this, as well.

[I've submitted a PR for this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/pull/1262), which so far has resulted in [some updated docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#avoiding-401-unauthorized-errors)